# What is the analogue of HttpRequestBase.Files collection in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate one project from .NET Framework to .NET Core 3.1.

In .NET Framework we have

```
namespace System.Web
{
    public abstract class HttpRequestBase
    //
        // Summary:
        //     When overridden in a derived class, gets the collection of files that were uploaded
        //     by the client, in multipart MIME format.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The files that were uploaded by the client. The items in the System.Web.HttpFileCollection
        //     object are of type System.Web.HttpPostedFile.
        public virtual HttpFileCollectionBase Files { get; }
```

What is the analogue of this collection in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` class? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have that in `Request.Form.Files`, but in a controller, you can expose a parameter of type `IFormFileCollection` (for many files) or `IFormFile` (for a single file). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm looking for.